# Python - memory usage

Tags: python

I am a computer engineer student and I started to work with Python. Now, my assignment is create an matrix but very large scale. How can I handle it in order to take less memory? I did some search and found "memory handler", but I cant be sure if the handler can bu used for this. Or are there any module in Python library?

Thank you.

Comment: If your matrix is sparse (has a lot of zeros) there are a few implementations in numpy to choose from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking into numpy and scipy. They are relatively thin layers on top of blocks of memory, and are usually quite efficient for matrix type calculations. If your matrix is large but sparse (ie most elements are 0), have a look at [scipy's sparse matrices](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).